# Use unicode(255) for all column types in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, unicode

I do not understand when to use the different lengths for calling unicode.  I have been using types.Unicode(255) for all my columns in my postgres database such as address, name, description, etc.  Is it unwise to do this?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  Here is how my current table looks like:
property_table = schema.Table('property', meta.metadata,
    schema.Column('id', types.Unicode(255), primary_key=True),
    schema.Column('name', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('address', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('city', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('state', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('zip', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by "unicode(255)" - there is no such data type in PostgreSQL:

```
# create table q (x unicode(255));
ERROR:  type "unicode" does not exist
LINE 1: create table q (x unicode(255));
                          ^
```

Maybe you meant varchar(255). In this case - let me ask: what will happen if you'll need 320 character description?

Personally I prefer to use TEXT datatype - since database generally doesn't care if the string is 100 or 1000 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth adding to depesz's answer that there are no performance penalties for using text type rather than varchar(n) or char(n) data types, so unless you need to set a hard limit for business purposes just use text. Even then, use text with a length constraint :-)

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of reasons to use proper datatypes in your databases. [Performance](http://www.sqlpass.org/LinkClick.aspx?link=http%3a%2f%2fsqlfool.com%2fcontent%2fPerformanceConsiderationsOfDataTypes.pdf&tabid=237&mid=819) (pdf) is the biggest concern, but there are other reasons too. For example:

- Dates will not sort properly unless they are a date datatype (usually a unix timestamp)
- You cannot use mathematical operators on numbers that are stored as strings
- "true" as a string does not equal boolean true